# ReactJs - i can't catch a variable outside of the axios' loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I Have a JSON DB and a React Component that fetch these datas.
Here is my JSON DB:

```
{
  "houses": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "house 1"       
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "house 2"        
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "house 3"
     }       
  ]
}
```

It is fetching by a ReactJS Component. When I do console.log() inside of a Axios' loop it works successfully. But inside of the render method it isn't working. How can I solve it?

```
class Houses extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      index:0,         
      currentHouse:[]      
    };      
  }

  componentDidMount() { 
    axios.get(URL_HOUSES)
      .then(res => {        
        this.setState({ index:0 })
        this.setState({ currentHouse: res.data})          
        //Here is working! It is returning the index and the current house's name      
        console.log('index:' + this.state.index)             
        console.log(
                     'Name of the current house:' +  
                      this.state.currentHouse[this.state.index].name
                    ) 
    }

  render() {                  

    return (
      <div>     
        //Here isn't working. It is returning an error message:  
        //TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

        <h3>{this.state.currentHouse[this.state.index].name}</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}   


export default Houses
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR check initial currentHouse array before displaying it in the render method.**

On the initial render of your component, there are no elements in the `currentHouse` array.

So when your component tried to print out your statement `this.state.currentHouse[this.state.index].name`, what it's actually trying to do is find the 0th position of an empty array `[]`. *This will evaluate to* `undefined`.

An option to fix this is set an initial value to the currentHouse array in the state, or check to see if there are values in the array. For example:

```
 <h3>{this.state.currentHouse.length && this.state.currentHouse[this.state.index].name}</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is that the `render()` method is trying to render data before that data is available. Try the following to resolve this issue:

```
class Houses extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      index:0,         
      currentHouse:[]      
    };      
  }

  componentDidMount() { 
    axios.get(URL_HOUSES)
      .then(res => {        
        /* Combine into single setState call (this is optional, but 
           makes for cleaner code. Note that calling setState will
           trigger the component to render() again, which will cause
           your currentHouse[0].name to be rendered into <h3> below  */
        this.setState({ index:0, currentHouse: res.data })
    }

  render() {                  

    /* Detect if currentHouse data is ready/avalible - if not, render
       a temporary loading message */
    if(this.state.currentHouse.length === 0) {
       return <p>Loading</p>
    } 

    /* If we reach this point, then there is data in this.state.currentHouse
       that can be accessed and rendered */
    return (
      <div>         
        <h3>{this.state.currentHouse[this.state.index].name}</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}   


export default Houses
```